# Reason to increase output impedance in a non-inverting op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, filter, active-filter

[image: Non inverting op-amp using LF356 with R2 added]

In the schematic above a non-inverting op-amp filter is shown.

Why is R2 added within the feedback loop? Does it serve any purpose?

Outside the feedback path (right before C2) it could serve as a current limitation, I guess.

After removing R2 there is no difference in the simulation, so why would we intentionally increase the output impedance of the op-amp?

Comment: Is there an output current limitation of the opamp? When starting up, the capacitor will act as a short.

Comment: Impedance matching?

Comment: Well where is this circuit being used, and what's the usual load? If the load is not how it will be in the intended system, the simulation result also does not give you results of the real system.

Comment: @DKNguyen It basically can't be impedance matching, because the feedback makes sure the op-amp tries to drive that point with zero impedance. For an ideal op-amp anyway.

Comment: Where did you find this circuit and what is its purpose? The resistor does little of value that I can see. It makes it less stable with capacitive load and does not affect the short-circuit power dissipation much.

Comment: @DKNguyen impedance matching how???

Comment: @Designalog Just couldn't think of anything better hence the question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Why is R2 added within the feedback loop? Does it serve any purpose?*

A purpose that it serves is to protect the op-amp from failing (or excessively over-heating) should the output becomes short-circuited (Vout connected to 0 volts). I think that the value shown (50 Ω) won't be very effective but, it will certainly take some power dissipation away from the op-amp in the case of an output short-circuit.

> *After removing R2 there is no difference in the simulation, so why
> would we intentionally increase the output impedance of the op-amp?*

Because the 50 Ω is still within the feedback loop of the op-amp, for normal light loading on the output, it will make no difference to the voltage amplification.

Answer (score 1):

This type of scheme is to decrease the amount of capacitance that the opamp "see's" on its output. If you were to decrease the series resistance beyond a certain point on the output its possible that the stability of the opamp would be affected. Look at the AC response and run a parameter sweep on the series resistor.

For more information on this scheme read this: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ask-the-applications-engineer-25.html

Comment: Can opamps become unstable from a series output capacitance?

Comment: Okay, i can somewhat identify my circuit in the linked article as 'In-loop compensation' However im missing the C_F. And in addition to that, if i add a capacitance as a load to the circuit, the added resistor **R2** lowers the 'peak' in the phase response. i.e. the point where a steep decline towards -180° is. So my understandig is, that adding R2 lowers the frequency where the op gets instable. Or am i getting anything wrong?

Comment: @dknguyen if the output is tied to ground (or another C to GND) then it becomes parallel capacitance which can destabilize it.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitance to ground at the output of an op amp acts with the output resistance to add a pole to the loop which can destabilize the amplifier.

One technique used to improve stability in the situation where a capacitive load to ground is present is to add a small resistor (say 100R) between the feedback take-off point and the load. This adds a zero to the loop, adding phase advance and improving stability margins.

Another technique used to improve stability is to add a small resistor between the op amp's output and the feedback take-off point (as in your circuit example) but for this technique to work a capacitor must also be added between the op amp's output and the inverting input. There is a pole and a zero associated with the load capacitance and a pole and zero associated with the feedback capacitance and the idea is that the two added components must have values such that their pole and zero cancel out the capacitive load's pole and zero giving zero phase through the feedback network and then the loop phase is only dependent on the phase through the op amp resulting in an improvement in stability margins.

The advantage of the second technique over the first technique is that the resistor is placed within the feedback loop and so there is very little amplitude reduction of the output signal compared with when the resistor is placed outside the feedback loop.